# Maven import scope not importing test dependencies

Tags: maven, import, dependency-management

I'd like to define a large number of both `compile` and `test` dependencies in a POM to be imported in to other POMs. Everything works as expected for the `compile` dependencies. But the `test` dependencies are not resolved in my project's POM.

Her's a minimalist example:

**POM to be imported:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.maven.import</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom-to-be-imported</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**POM using the import:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.maven.import</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom-using-import</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.maven.import</groupId>
            <artifactId>pom-to-be-imported</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I run a `dependency:tree`, it only shows the `compile` dependencies of `commons-lang3`, but not the JUnit `test` dependency:

```
>mvn dependency:tree
. . .
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ pom-using-import ---
[INFO] com.example.maven.import:pom-using-import:pom:1
[INFO] \- com.example.maven.import:pom-to-be-imported:pom:1:import
[INFO]    \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8:runtime
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***How can I get the `test` dependencies to be imported as well?*** I did not find anything in the [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) indicating that import only works for `compile` dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import` scope is only intended for use inside the `dependencyManagement` section. (This concept is also called BOM in maven.) From the [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> - import
>
> This scope is only supported on a dependency of type pom in the
>   <dependencyManagement> section.

You have a couple of options to achieve what I think you want:

1. Use the import mechanism correctly by adding the `import` scoped dependency to a `dependencyManagement` section in pom-using-import. You can then remove the `<dependencies>` section in the 'pom-to-be-imported'. Each "importing pom" must explicitly list all dependencies in the `<dependencies>` section, but you don't have to give a version (or scope).

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.maven.import</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom-to-be-imported</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependencyManagement>
```

2. If all your "importing poms" need the same dependencies, you can use inheritance by declaring the 'pom-to-be-imported' as parent instead of using import:

```xml
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
      <groupId>com.example.maven.import</groupId>
      <artifactId>pom-to-be-imported</artifactId> <!-- Rename it to e.g. 'parent' -->
      <version>1</version>
      <relativePath>../pom-to-be-imported/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>pom-using-import</artifactId>
```

Alternative 2 is probably closest to what you want.